# how to always show text in parallax design

Tags: css, parallax

Is there a way to show the text even when the background is parallaxing? I want the text float to the front no matter what. I have tried experimenting with the z-index on the text but got no luck.

http://jsfiddle.net/zuuptm3v/

HTML

```
<div id="section1" class="section">
  <div class="text">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis  
   autem quae quisquam doloribus velit optio numquam beatae natus,  
   nihil, sapiente perferendis, cumque itaque quaerat corrupti voluptate 
   ducimus explicabo saepe officia.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis 
   autem quae quisquam doloribus velit optio numquam beatae natus, 
   nihil, sapiente perferendis, cumque itaque quaerat corrupti voluptate 
   ducimus explicabo saepe officia.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis 
   autem quae quisquam doloribus velit optio numquam beatae natus, 
   nihil, sapiente perferendis, cumque itaque quaerat corrupti voluptate 
   ducimus explicabo saepe officia.
 </div>
</div>

<div id="section2" class="section">
 <div class="text">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis 
 autem quae quisquam doloribus velit optio numquam beatae natus, nihil, 
 sapiente perferendis, cumque itaque quaerat corrupti voluptate ducimus 
 explicabo saepe officia.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis 
 autem quae quisquam doloribus velit optio numquam beatae natus, nihil, 
 sapiente perferendis, cumque itaque quaerat corrupti voluptate ducimus 
 explicabo saepe officia.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis 
 autem quae quisquam doloribus velit optio numquam beatae natus, nihil, 
 sapiente perferendis, cumque itaque quaerat corrupti voluptate ducimus 
 explicabo saepe officia.
 </div>
</div>

<div id="section3" class="section">
 <div class="text">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis 
 autem quae quisquam doloribus velit optio numquam beatae natus, nihil, 
 sapiente perferendis, cumque itaque quaerat corrupti voluptate ducimus 
 explicabo saepe officia.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis 
 autem quae quisquam doloribus velit optio numquam beatae natus, nihil, 
 sapiente perferendis, cumque itaque quaerat corrupti voluptate ducimus 
 explicabo saepe officia.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis 
 autem quae quisquam doloribus velit optio numquam beatae natus, nihil, 
 sapiente perferendis, cumque itaque quaerat corrupti voluptate ducimus 
 explicabo saepe officia.
 </div>
</div>

<div id="section2" class="section">
 <div class="text">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis 
 autem quae quisquam doloribus velit optio numquam beatae natus, nihil, 
 sapiente perferendis, cumque itaque quaerat corrupti voluptate ducimus 
 explicabo saepe officia.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis 
 autem quae quisquam doloribus velit optio numquam beatae natus, nihil, 
 sapiente perferendis, cumque itaque quaerat corrupti voluptate ducimus 
 explicabo saepe officia.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis 
 autem quae quisquam doloribus velit optio numquam beatae natus, nihil, 
 sapiente perferendis, cumque itaque quaerat corrupti voluptate ducimus  
 explicabo saepe officia.
 </div>
</div>     
</div>
```

CSS

```
 /* Default State */
.control {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed!important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  height: 100%;

 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 perspective: 1px;
}

.control ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 20px!important;
  line-height: 105%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 605;
}

 .control ul li a{
   color: #FFF;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 .control ul li a:hover{
   color: #6C7A89;
 }

 /* Toggled State */
 input[type=checkbox]#toggle-1:checked ~ .control {
 left: 0px!important; 
 }

 /*SETUP*/

 .control .section {
 position: relative;
 padding: 20% 10%!important;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;

 background: 50% 50% / cover;

}

/*SECTION DATA BOXES*/

.text {
 width: 50%;
 padding: 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: rgba(200,200,200, 0);
}

#section1 .text {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;

}

#section2 .text {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
}

#section3 .text {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
}

.header{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
}

/*SECTION IMAGES*/

 #title {
  background: orange;
  background-attachment: fixed; 
}

 #section1 {
  background: yellow;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index: -1;
}

 #section2 {
  background: purple;
  background-attachment: fixed;
 }

 #section3 {
  background: green;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index: -1;
 }

 #section4 { background: #111; }
```

Comment: `z-index` only works on elements that have a non-default `position` property applied to them.